# IncludeNativeBool Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'm not sure if this is a bug but it only happens with the constant `includeNativeBool true` after switching themes, once I navigate through menus it shows up, I highlighted it with red as you can see in the picture below. I want to deactivate that pop up on the top. Is this a constant which is making this pops up at the top?

***obs: Android Device***

[image: includeNativeBool true]

Comment: This happens in some edge cases where one manipulates command behavior or the toolbar. Make sure to remove references to commandBehavior from your theme constants and similar things from code.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I've removed all `commandBehavior` constants and I didn't find similar references in my code. What you mean by toolbar? What toolbars command?

Comment: Do you manipulate the toolbar in a "creative" way? Did you disable global toolbar or something?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I didn't disable the global toolbar, the only lines in my code regarding toolbar which i set are: `Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false);` and by default `Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog There is a critical issue when changing from landscape to portrait mode, spanlabels are being cut off, I mean its texts disappear, the transition between landscape to portrait mode is causing spanlabels to get its texts capped with Button, that's a weird thing.

Comment: Please try to reproduce it as an isolated test case